# WEBAR camera does not appear the first time it is opened

Tags: three.js, camera, webxr

I have a question for webxr using threejs where when the web page is loaded for the first time you have to open start ar 2 times then the camera turns on, when you start it the first time the camera goes blank  is there any solution for that?[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00gZN.jpg)